# Collision Avoidance using ogre3 on visual 2010

Tags: c++, ogre3d

I work with ogre3d and visual 2010, I have problem of implementation collision avoidance of two robot walking next to each other, I want : the first robot stops and the athor keep walking then the first robot walking.

Comment: Step one: Look up from the iPad and check left and right before crossing the street....

Comment: Are you one of the robots?

Comment: No i mean , i want a robot stops for 2 second then he keep walking

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way of doing it with Ogre is checking intersection between your Entities' axis aligned bounding boxes.

For example:

```
  Ogre::Entity *robot1(NULL), *robot2(NULL);
  Ogre::AnimationState* move_anim(NULL);
  Ogre::Real stop_t_s(0.0f);

  void app::init() {
    robot1 = scene_mgr_->createEntity("robot.mesh");
    robot2 = scene_mgr_->createEntity("robot.mesh");
    move_anim = robot1->getAnimationState("Walk");
    move_anim->setLoop(true);
    move_anim->setEnabled(true);
    root_->startRendering();
  }
  void app::frameRenderingQueued(const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt) {
    if (move_anim->getEnabled()) {
      move_anim->addTime(evt.timeSinceLastFrame);
    }
    else {
      stop_t_s += evt.timeSinceLastFrame;
      if (stop_t_s > 2.0f) {
        move_anim->setEnabled(true);
        stop_t_s = 0.0f;
      }
    }
    if (robot1->getBoundingBox().intersects(robot2->getBoundingBox())) {
      move_anim->setEnabled(false);
      /* more collide routine */
    }
    else {
      /* normal routine */
    }
  }
```

*If you want to have more precise collision shapes you should consider using a physics engine to handle it*

---

Update: I've added an example for stopping the `"Walk"` animation in `robot.mesh` upon collision and restart it after 2 seconds. For more details on animation control see [Ogre Intermediate Tutorial 1](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Intermediate%20Tutorial%201)

Comment: My problem is how to make a robot stops for 2 second then walks

Comment: I see. Clarify next time better in question ;) I will add it to my answer, based on the corresponding [ogre tutorial](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Intermediate+Tutorial+1)